# Inodes on /run filesystem is full

Tags: linux, rhel, docker, kubernetes, amazon-linux

Inode on /run is getting full for all our nodes that are being managed by EKS, especially for small instances like t3a.medium below output from df -i.

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs         485K   310  485K    1% /dev
tmpfs            488K     3  488K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1.5M  1.4M  118K   92% /run
tmpfs            488K    16  488K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1    10M  108K  9.9M    2% /
tmpfs            488K    16  488K    1% /tmp
```

I have also checked total number inodes consumed by directories and files in /run by executing command `{ sudo find /run -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n; } 2>/dev/null`, and a total number of inodes consumed by files and folders in /run is 770.

I have also checked there are no dangling container images as such and also checked open files for all the processes on the system none are suspicious, Not sure which folder is taking up all the inodes of the /run.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Please show us the results of the following commands `uptime` and `mount|grep /run`.

Comment: Output from uptime command is  07:28:42 up 80 days, 15:15,  0 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.72, 0.85

Comment: and out from mount | grep /run is tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,size=2097152k,nr_inodes=1498760,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/default type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/0469e97f11dd type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/f10b83e674f6 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/08431f90ddb0 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/023bd3262040 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)

Comment: nsfs on /run/docker/netns/c6626ac50925 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/05fbe36dfff3 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/37c8484eb9a6 type nsfs (rw,seclabel)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=399012k,mode=700)

Comment: provided output in 2 comments because of limitation of characters